# Using environment variables in URL for data source

Tags: qgis, wfs, environment-variable

I have a QGIS project file that I want to distribute to a number of users. The project contains several WFS layers that users can also submit changes to. The WFS layers are hosted as a service and are out of my control.

The URL is as follows:

```
fakegisservice.com/wfs/[username]@[database]/[schema]/[crs]
```

User 1, Joe, should connect using:

```
fakegisservice.com/wfs/joe@internaldb/management/25832
```

But user 2, Jane, should use:

```
fakegisservice.com/wfs/jane@internaldb/management/25832
```

I want a solution where no one has to manually edit anything in the QGIS project file. I expect that I will make revisions to the QGIS file, and I don't want to deal with this, every time I send out a new revision.

Lets assume that the username on the local system is the same username that should be used for the WFS connection.

On most operating systems, the username is saved in an enviromentvariable called "USER".

Is this possible to specify the URL so it depends on this variable?

I have experimented with setting the URL to various things similar to the examples below, but without luck.

- `fakegisservice.com/wfs/${USER}@internaldb/management/25832`
- `fakegisservice.com/wfs/{USER}@internaldb/management/25832`
- `fakegisservice.com/wfs/{%USER%}@internaldb/management/25832`

Comment: `fakegisservice.com/wfs/[username]@[database]/[schema]/[crs]` doesn't look like a WFS URL.  What would a GetCapabilities request look like?

Comment: I don't understand too well. Do these two screenshots answer your question? https://i.imgur.com/BeCgCUf.png

Comment: My bad, it's just odd to see crs in the URL stem, because there is a mechanism to ask for any supported CRS through a request parameter.

Comment: On Windows the user is held in `USERNAME` environment variable.  In QGIS the same information is held in Global variable `user_account_name`

Comment: @nmtoken: Yes. But how do I make QGIS automatically use user_account_name in the relevant URLs. I need QGIS to automatically do the evaluation/substitution somehow.